# Invalid character in identifier fix?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-unicode

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
file.read()
new = 'first_filter_' + filename
words.save(new)
#words = text.split(' ')
```

Error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Your description of the problem makes no sense. Please show your code and the actual error message.

Comment: file = open(filename, 'r')
    file.read()
    new = 'first_filter_' + filename
    words.save(new)
the code above can't read the file because of the character '¥' which is unrecognizable. Is there any way to make the code disregard that character?

Comment: No, post your real code and the full, actual error message. In your question.

Comment: That doesn't say `Invalid character in identifier`.

Comment: That's not the complete code. You're getting an error from combining a Unicode str with a regular str. Please provide all the code and a complete stack trace